# "badly formed hexadecimal UUID string" when filtering a GraphQL query on multiple IDs (Graphene-Django)

Tags: django, graphql, django-filter, graphene-python

I have Django models `Photo` and `Tag` which have a many-to-many relationship joined through the model `PhotoTag`. This is the relevant bit from models.py - note they inherit from `UUIDModel` so have UUIDs as the primary key rather than the default auto-increment ID.

### Models

```
class Photo(UUIDModel):
    taken_at                            = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    taken_by                            = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    aperture                            = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    exposure                            = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)
    iso_speed                           = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    ...

class Tag(UUIDModel):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...

class PhotoTag(UUIDModel):
    photo       = models.ForeignKey(Photo, related_name='photo_tags')
    tag         = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='photo_tags')
    ...
```

For the Graphene-Django schema I have two filters defined for `all_photos` - fetching photos by tag names and fetching by tag ids where tag is assigned through the `photo_tags` relationship. The schema definition is below - `photo_tags__tag__id = graphene.String()` is my attempt to prevent the error **badly formed hexadecimal UUID string** and I hoped that making it a `graphene.String()` would allow it to be split.

### Schema

```
class CustomNode(graphene.Node):
    class Meta:
        name = 'Node'

    @staticmethod
    def to_global_id(type, id):
        return id

class PhotoInterface(graphene.Interface):
    photo_tags__tag__id = graphene.String()

class PhotoNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        interfaces = (CustomNode, PhotoInterface)

class PhotoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = {
            'photo_tags__tag__id': ['exact', 'in'],
            'photo_tags__tag__name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'in'],
        }

class Query(object):
    all_photos = DjangoFilterConnectionField(PhotoNode, filterset_class=PhotoFilter)
```

Below is the type of query I would like to run. The user is allowed to select multiple tags and the result would be an intersection of the photos that match. `in` is probably not the right filter to use in this case so any advice on that would be appreciated.

### Query

```
{
  allPhotos(photoTags_Tag_Id_In: "f24c88fe-74ee-4b2d-beaf-3da6f68cfe3c,6522e86e-fcb4-4a17-8887-f2560d3fe3da") {
    pageInfo {
      startCursor
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        takenAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Filtering by `tag__name`as below  works without error (though it is a union rather than intersection).

```
allPhotos(photoTags_Tag_Name_In: "Cat,Bike") { ... }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but there is an underdocumented UUID type in graphene -- https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/uuid.py

Comment: Cool, thanks @MarkChackerian. I'm sure I'll be digging around that area soon.